# Value Error: module PIL Image is not a class

Tags: ros, python, errors, networking

This is the node I've written in rospy. It opens a socket connection and then converts the received image to < ndarray > and then < sensormsg.Image > and publishes it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError  
import cv2  
from PIL import Image  
import numpy

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('', 8000))

bridge = CvBridge()


def photo_publisher():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('/android', Image, queue_size=1)  # topic name
    rospy.init_node('photo_publisher', anonymous=False)  # node name
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)  # Hz: loop is run 10 times per second
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        server.listen()
        print("Listening")

        client_socket, client_address = server.accept()
        print("Connected with {}".format(client_address))

        file = open('server_image.jpg', "wb")

        image_chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)
        while image_chunk:
            file.write(image_chunk)
            image_chunk = client_socket.recv(2048)

        file.close()
        client_socket.close()

        # convert to cv mat for cv_bridge
        img = Image.open("server_image.jpg")
        np_img = numpy.array(img)

        # convert to ros format
        msg = bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(np_img, "bgr8")
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        photo_publisher()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

However I receive this error when I roslaunch it

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/user/HS402/sf00894/rsatest_ws/src/vision/scripts/image_publisher.py", line 51, in < module > 
photo_publisher() 
File "/user/HS402/sf00894/rsatest_ws/src/vision/scripts/image_publisher.py", line 19, in photo_publisher 
pub = rospy.Publisher('/android', Image, queue_size=1)  # topic name
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 842 in __init__
super(Publisher, self).__init__(name, data_class, Registration.PUB)
File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 142 in __init__
raise ValueError("data_class [%s] is not a class"%data_class)
ValueError: data_class [<module 'PIL.Image' from "/user/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/image.pyc'>] is not a class
```

Is such a node with a socket server even appropriate? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why are you posting this question twice?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in that you are importing `Image` from `PIL` and from `sensor_msg.msg`. You could solve it by using an alias for `PIL` (or for `sensor_msg` if you prefer):

```py
from PIL import Image as Img
```

Comment: please don't post answers on duplicate questions